# Size of area in Web Mercator

Tags: coordinate-system, coordinates, sentinel-2, web-mercator, sentinel-hub

I downloaded a satellite image from Sentinel Hub. I requested a 10,000 x 10,000m image in Web Mercator (EPSG:3857).

Here is a piece of code that I use:

```
bbox = BBox(bbox=[x, y, x + 10000, y + 10000], crs='3857')
```

When I open the downloaded GeoTIFF in QGIS, I see that the downloaded image is 10,000 x 10,000m and the bbox is correct (the one that I requested).

However, when I check the size of downloaded area in Google Maps, the area is about 5,000 x 5,000 m. Could someone explain why?

Alternatively, I can open the image in Google Earth and check its size using the ruler tool. It is also 5,000 x 5,000 m.

Comment: This depends on the region on earth that you create this BBOX for. EPSG:3587 is highly distorted anywhere that is not the equator.

Comment: The poles are infinitely far from the Equator in Web Mercator, so distance measurement is useless in that projection.

Comment: Ok, so I cannot rely on Web Mercator coordinates to measure distance. Thanks!